# Not able to check the Checkbox on Salesfoce standard page layout

Tags: checkbox

We have custom checkbox field (Is Active) on the standard page layout, check box is not able to check when we click on Check box. If we click on checkbox field label name check box is getting checked. Could anyone pls let me know what is issue why checkbox is not getting checked when we click on Checkbox.

[image]

Comment: Can you check if the field is readonly at pagelayout?

Comment: @DhananjayPatil No, its not read only field.

Comment: Maybe it's read only for the user's profile. Then it will become read only on page layout as well.